# How to set width padding that handles window resizing

Tags: html, css

I have a menu which has 5 items as unordered list.I can adjust padding in single pc but if the screen size changes the layout also changes in another pc.I used percentage but that too is not working.

```
.menu{

opacity:70%;
}
.menu ul{
width:100%;

display:inline;



}
.menu ul li{
font-size: x-large;
float: left;
list-style: none;
text-decoration: none;

color:yellow;
background-color:green;
padding:10px 6%;
box-sizing:border-box;

}
```

Comment: What is "pc"? personal computer?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `vh` and `vw` property.
For example,
`#box { padding: 10vh 30vw}`

In this example the top and bottom padding will be 1/10 of the screen.
For the right and left padding will be 3/10 of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't have a menu that is responsive that way. If it fits on a big screen, it may can't fit in a smaller screen (or you will have to reduce the font size, but maybe it will not be readable anymore)

Otherwise, if you want something that stays in one line, I strongly recommend you to use `flex` positioning.

You can learn more about Flex [following this link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
}

.container > * {
 flex: 1;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span>item 1</span>
    <span>item 2</span>
    <span>item 3</span>
    <span>item 4</span>
    <span>item 5</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try including float attribute..

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are suggesting ? Thanks :)